How to restore the icon of explorer?
the search icon conflicts with the image of the file.I want to restore the style of the search icon.I try to set the icon theme, but it didn't work.I don't know what to do.I look forward to your help.enter image description here

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
